# Python 3.6.4 error: help('modules') and tornado pyzmq?

Tags: python, tornado, pyzmq

```
Strange error on python 3.6.4 :

C:\Python364>python.exe
Python 3.6.4 (v3.6.4:d48eceb, Dec 19 2017, 06:54:40) [MSC v.1900 64 bit (AMD64)]
 on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> help('modules')

Please wait a moment while I gather a list of all available modules...

C:\Python364\lib\site-packages\IPython\kernel\__init__.py:13: ShimWarning: The `
IPython.kernel` package has been deprecated since IPython 4.0.You should import
from ipykernel or jupyter_client instead.
  "You should import from ipykernel or jupyter_client instead.", ShimWarning)
C:\Python364\lib\site-packages\qtawesome\iconic_font.py:268: UserWarning: You need to have a running QApplication to use QtAwesome!
  warnings.warn("You need to have a running "
C:\Python364\lib\pkgutil.py:107: VisibleDeprecationWarning: zmq.eventloop.minitornado is deprecated in pyzmq 14.0 and will be removed.
    Install tornado itself to use zmq with the tornado IOLoop.

  yield from walk_packages(path, info.name+'.', onerror)
IPython             bleach              imghdr              rope
```

The error is not show after I install nose python module and run again :

```
help('modules')
```

I don't think this error is not solved. 
How to check and fix this error ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can ignore these warnings. Some of the packages you have installed contain deprecated modules that should not be used in new code but are still provided for backwards compatibility. `help('modules')` imports everything it can, so it looks like it's trying to use these deprecated modules and triggers the warning.

If you see these warnings anywhere other than `help('modules')`, action may be required.

Comment: Is a collateral issue related to installing python modules and and spyder IDE , solving depends on which modules are involved and incompatibility.
I do not think I can find a correct answer now, but I accept it as a way to solve it.